# Check char in an char array against a integer

Tags: java

I have a character array that looks like this:

[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

I wanted to check if a index supplied by the user matches 1:

```
                System.out.println("Enter the file index you want");
                int fileIndex = input.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println("File you are looking for is " + myFile[fileIndex]);
```

When I enter 1 it returns File you are looking for is 1

Which is what I want:

But when the result is 1, I wanted to do something:

```
                if(myFile[fileIndex] == (char)1) {
                    //Do something because the char at this index is 1
                    System.out.println("HERE")
                }
```

However, even when `myFile[fileIndex]` is 1 the if condition does not work. What is the right way to check a character against a integer?

Comment: The character `'1'` is the integer 49 (as encoded in Unicode). By doing `(char) 1`, you're getting the start of heading character. Use `'1'` or `49` instead.

Comment: Did you try Interger.valueOf(character ) or Integer.toString() Methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if((char)myFile[fileIndex] == '1') {
    System.out.println("HERE")
}
```

Comment: I tried if((char)myFile[fileIndex] == "1") before and it did not work. So we cannot use "".

Comment: @goxarad784 Double quotes are for strings, single quotes are for characters. I would recommend learning the basics of Java syntax before going on to more advanced stuff